# Why would mages think the spell analysis is useless?

Tags: magic, balancing-magic-systems

The world setting is high fantasy with some game elements (Just a status screen) and a fair amount of realism. Even with magic, it's fairly easy to die. The magic system is a hard type. To use a spell there are guiding rules to follow:

1. The Caster must have enough understanding of a spell for it to be registered as a spell in the system.
2. The Caster must have enough mana to cast the spell, if the required amount of mana is unavailable the caster's health will be used in compensation (leading to death in most cases).
3. The Casters proficiency with a spell determines its success rate and its power. There are hard limits to the power of a spell. e.g fireball at most has the power of a grenade at peak proficiency.
4. Free casting allows a caster to modify a spell they are using but is very dangerous to the caster, requires a lot of trial and error, a large volume of information. It is best done outside of combat.
5. You can acquire spells through Items and Spellbooks. Items have the spell attached as an enchantment and are not considered a spell the caster knows by the system. Spellbooks impart the preliminary understanding of a spell to the reader making them a spell recognised as known to the caster by the system.
6. The system does not aid the caster in any way only giving them an overview of their own abilities.

With these known rules, I want to know the reasoning as to why most mages would look down upon and call the Analysis spell useless.

Analysis spell definition:
Analyses a target and provides the information to the caster.
MP cost: 10

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because if questions have many valid answers then they're too broad for this site. Note how the only existing answer lists 3 different reasons why this could be the case.

Comment: This could be an interesting question with more detail but "*provides the information to the caster*" doesn't really provide much to work with.  More specifics like "what information is provided?",  "how is it provided?", etc. would help flesh out the limitations of the spell and help everyone here provide better answers for you.

Comment: I agree with @sphennings, as asked this question is too broad and too opinion-based. The [help/on-topic] requires answers to be specific and answerable (with a reasonable degree of objectivity) and the [help/dont-ask] further expects questions to not be open-ended. The phrase, "because my little sister doesn't like the word 'analysis'" is a legitimate answer to this question, but shouldn't be. Worse, this is very story-based as you're allowing non-rule-based answers. An example rule-based answer could be "because, filling the mage's head with info, it causes splitting headaches."

Comment: What are the costs for other spells? It would be great if you could provide information that would allow a comparison between different spells based on their cost and utility. Plus, what exactly does the Analysis spell do? Another important point is whether Analysis is the only way to increase comprehension or not. For example, if fireball costs 1 MP and each cast increases understanding by 1 point and max proficiency is achieved at 10 points, casting Analysis that gives only 5 points of understanding for 10 MP may be inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

Possibilities:

The cost is high relative to other uses.

The information is frequently useless

The spell can only be cast in situations where you are close enough to be harmed,  making it dangerous

Answer (score 1):

**Information overload**

You've not specifically stated exactly how much information the spell gives to the caster, so I'm going to assume it gives them the whole turkey, absolutely anything and everything about the target. Our minds are incapable of processing so much information in one instance. Not only would the spell give useful physical information, volume, density, weight, stat parameters for things who're alive(game elements), it would also give you a whole load of things that are utterly useless for most situations and due to the useful information being intermixed with the useless information the actual information a caster would want to use is muddled and equivalent to gibberish.

Trying to grasp the flood of information will also likely send someone into some sort of mentally catatonic state, or force them to simply draw a blank in their incapability to understand the whole picture. You may very well be able to pick out individual pieces of information but it would be like grasping at a torrential river full of leaves, the leaves being motes of information, what are the odds of you actually catching the leaf you want?

In order to prevent the flood of useless information the spell Analysis has been modified toward various specific kinds of information a caster would want. Analyze Stats, Analyze Memories, Analyze Travel History, Analyze Weight, etc.

Answer (score 0):

## Each Spell is a unique formula developed by the caster:

A recipe is something you use to make a dish you've never made before. A spell book is a well-written recipe that fills in all the details. But an analysis spell is like taking a loaf of bread and trying to reverse-engineer it without knowing exactly what the loaf of bread is. You get an ingredient list of what went into it. But the same list of ingredients can go into pancakes, or bread, or a paste to give to your kids to play with.

What you do with those ingredients is crucial. And every wizard makes his own formula by trail and error, which is why practice is crucial. Baking a loaf of bread at the right temperature is crucial, but so is not baking play-dough. Maybe one wizard really does add THAT much "salt" to his bread, and another mixes in butter and makes a roux for alfredo sauce. But the analysis spell only gives you an ingredient list.

It might have uses. If you wanted to make a counter-spell, it tells you what will disrupt the recipe. But mostly the individual nature of intent is such that unless you are trying to recreate a hyper-specific effect and not just the general intent, you're better off using trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

**The Spell only Retrieves Known Information**

The spell does not learn new information. It only copies knowledge from a local expert into your head. So you cannot Analyse artefacts from a long-dead civilization, unless there is a Professor of Archaeology nearby who has already analysed the artefacts the old-fashioned way.

If the expert is too far away away the spell requires a prohibitive amount of mana or components such as butterfly testicle powder. On the other hand if the expert is nearby (in the same city) it is usually easier to locate the expert directly -- either by magical or mundane means -- and ask them questions.

The main situation where the spell is useful is when the expert is too high-profile to meet with you. In that case you must learn the spell or locate a wizard who already knows the spell and pay them for the service. This is preferable to learning a spell that you might otherwise use only once a year.